# How to add Favicon icon in email template?

Tags: wordpress, html-email

We are using Wordpress website with Email template, all emails working fine, but our requirement is showing Favicon icon in our Email template.

How to pass Favicon icon in my email template?

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question. Do you want to have a seperate favicon for a seperate page? or do you want to add a favicon to an actual email? Because a email is not loaded in a webbrowser but in a mailclient. But if you mean the first option, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763010/new-update-favicon-per-page

Comment: Do you mean a favicon as displayed in a browser tab? Or a profile photo / icon as display by the sender name in an inbox?

Comment: Yes @Ted : a profile photo / icon as display by the sender name in an inbox , same as showing in our gmail account with sender (gmail id)

Comment: @Deepak thanks for clarifying. I included an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

These emails in Gmail / Google Inbox are known as [glanceable newsletters](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2016/04/inbox-by-gmail-better-way-to-keep-track.html). At the time of this answer, this is enabled for only a few email senders. So for the time being, the rest of us are out of luck.

In the meantime, we can start marking up our emails in anticipation of this feature eventually being enabled for the masses. It's not 100% clear how Google is building out these previews, but they provide [some related documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/article#use_cases) on email coding guidelines. We can also use [schema markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/) to specify what's what in an email so Google (or whoever else) can intelligently build previews. The best rundown I've seen so far is [on Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/inbox-by-gmail-update-what-you-need-to-know-about-glanceable-newsletters).

But for the time being, other than setting a Google+ profile picture, there's not much we can do except wait for Google to roll this out further.